# Setting classpath for a JAR

Tags: java, jar, classpath

I have a standalone java project. I have performed a maven clean install. I now go into the target\classes folder via command prompt and set all the required files in classpath. Now I execute the main class. The result is being displayed.

Now I move back to target folder via command prompt and try to execute the jar file (jar file has a manifest file where the main class is defined).

```
Java -cp %CLASSPATH% -jar Destination-01.19-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Now I get the below exception. I have also removed the classpath attribute from the statement above but still get the same exception.The required class is set in classpath variable which is the reason why I was able to run the main class without using the -jar attribute.

Exception in thread "Main Thread" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/co
mons/logging/LogFactory

Comment: I think you need to put the classpath in you MANIFEST file

Comment: Check [this too](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510071/maven-how-can-i-add-an-arbitrary-classpath-entry-to-a-jar)

Comment: No is not. Try printing `echo %CLASSPATH%`  and see if the **jar** file containing the LogFactory class is there.

Comment: Thanks. It is in the classpath - did echo %CLASSPATH%:.m2\repository\commons-logging\commons-logging
\1.1\commons-logging-1.1.jar;.m2\repository\log4j\log4j\1.2.14\l
og4j-1.2.14.jar; If it is not in the classpath , then I guess the stand alone main class should also not get executed.

Comment: Thanks Jake and Ring Bearer. I will try it out - I am using Maven. Wouldn't the jar take anything that is set outside?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `-jar` this is the sole mechanism setting the classpath for the program.

You must either have all the jars you need listed in the Class-Path line in the manifest (which implies they need to be findable in the local file system) or create a custom class loader capable of locating the jar you need.

Answer (score 4):

It seems -cp and -jar are incompatible.  You need to put the classpath in the manifest

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html

If you want maven to automatically update the classpath, see: -

http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/examples/classpath.html

Comment: Thanks Peter! I have set one dependency in <systemPath> - but this not getting added to classpath in manifest.