# Dependent class can't be found when invoke by java -classpath xxx -jar jarfile, but can be found by java -classpath xx class

Tags: java, command-line, invoke

Case 1:

```
java  -cp LRS3rdPartyClient.jar -jar tasks.jar
```

Case 2:

```
java -classpath LRS3rdPartyClient.jar;tasks.jar com.lombardrisk.build.WaitForServerStart
```

`Case 1` does not execute, because a class, which resides in `LRS3rdPartyClient.jar` cannot be found, whereas the `Case 2` executes properly.

I'am quite confused.

Answer (score 1):

When using `-jar`, [the classpath is ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8789683/setting-classpath-for-a-jar). Only the classpath specified in the jar file's manifest is used.