# Executable JAR ignores its own Class-Path attribute

Tags: java, jar, classpath

I used the instructions found at [Maven - how can I add an arbitrary classpath entry to a jar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5893391/14731) to add an arbitrary entry to the `Class-Path` attribute. Here is my `MANIFEST.MF` file:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: jace-runtime.jar
Main-Class: org.jace.examples.Test
```

I defined org.jace.examples.Test as follows:

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("classpath: " + System.getProperty("java.class.path"));
        System.out.println("PeerExample: " + Class.forName("org.jace.util.ShutdownHook"));
    }
}
```

where `org.jace.util.ShutdownHook` is defined in `jace-runtime.jar`. When I invoke `java -jar peer_example1.jar` I get the following output:

`classpath: peer_example1.jar`
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jace.util.ShutdownHook

In other words, Java is adding the executable JAR file to the classpath but ignoring `Class-Path`. If I invoke `java -cp jace-runtime.jar;peer_example1.jar org.jace.examples.Test` I get the expected output:

`classpath: jace-runtime.jar;peer_example1.jar`

Any ideas?

Comment: You might need ../jace-runtime.jar if the jar root is considered as the current working directory.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: I just tried it. It didn't work.

Comment: But have you tried accessing a class in that other jar? It seems that java.class.path doesn't reflect the classpath read in from the manifest.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: Yes, I used Class.forName() to look up a class defined in jace-runtime.jar and it was not found.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Answering my own question:

1. Adding arbitrary entries to `Class-Path` is fine on its own. The problem arises when you enable JAR indexing using:

   ```
   <configuration>
     <archive>
       <index>true</index>
     </archive>
   </configuration>
   ```

   Maven will omit your entries from `META-INF/INDEX.LIST`.
2. When you use the JAR at runtime, Java will look at INDEX.LIST for finding classes, not MANIFEST.MF.
3. Because your entries are missing from INDEX.LIST, they will not be found by the classloader, no matter what the manifest says.

A simple workaround is to disable JAR indexing. I'm not sure how to inject an arbitrary `Class-Path` with indexing enabled.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this more than once. I have had the same issue for about a year. Couldn't find the cause until I saw this. In my case, I don't have this code in my .pom file but an INDEX.LIST is still being generated. At least, now I know where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

For those that may otherwise be unaware, the executable archive mechanism takes the manifest classpath and uses it to load classes **external** to the archive.

So if you are expecting a WAR with a manifest classpath of WEB-INF/classes to find classes in the WEB-INF/classes entry **inside** the archive then you will be disappointed.

Answer (score -4):

Per the tooldocs page for the jar option - [Link to docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html)

> When you use this option, the JAR file is the source of all user classes, and other user class path settings are ignored.

Comment: -1: The documentation refers to the fact that the `-cp/-classpath` command-line option gets ignored in favor of the `Class-Path` which I am using, so this isn't the problem.