# Windows Server 2003 JDBC driver

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, windows-server-2003

I wrote a simple multiplayer JAVA app that can connect to MySQL using JDBC driver.
I ended up packing it up in .jar file. When I was testing on my local machine MacOS, it was fine. (I don't exactly remember all the steps to set up JDBC driver, because it was year ago when I wrote this app). The app at this time connects to an external database on another server (I didn't change that because it had no problems). It would be another error if it was a problem with the remote database.

Now, when I need to put it on production on Windows Server 2003, I keep getting the standard error :

```
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
And I don't get it, because I think I've done the steps right:
0. Installed Java
1. downloaded this: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/
2. added it to the same folder where the app.jar is
3. wrote in cmd: set CLASSPATH =.;C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\tvplan_exchange\mysql-connector-java-5.1.28-bin.jar
4. tested the variable: echo %CLASSPATH% and it showed the same path
5. runned the app: java -jar app.jar
6. got the error:
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at svagers.Db.connect(Db.java:21)
    at svagers.Server.main(Server.java:58)
    MYSQL ERRORcom.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

Well, for those who think that using app like this is a security error - no worries, that is not a problem, I just need it to be running not to consider risks :)

This is the environment:
OS: Windows Server 2003 (Standard Edition, Service Pack 2)
Java: 1.7.0_45 (SE Runtime Environment

Comment: Did you load your MySQL driver by calling: `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");`?

Comment: This is the line: Class.forName(driver).newInstance(); where driver is  com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Comment: And as I said - everything should be fine in the code, because I get it up and running on my computer (I used my computer as a server to connect from other computers for a developement period)

Comment: Then you didn't add properly your mysql-connector dependency to classpath.

Comment: Can you tell me how to do that properly? I added it like I wrote: set CLASSPATH =.;C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\tvplan_exchange\mysql-connector-java-5.1.28-bin.jar and the directory exists, and the file with that name exists too. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I was going to say "run the app with `java -cp %CLASSPATH% -jar app.jar`" but then remembered you can't have both: you use *either* -jar *or* -cp. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15930980/3080094) answer.