# Spring Boot and external configurations

Tags: spring, deployment, spring-boot

I am trying to make a Spring Boot application. Everything is fine once I deploy to the fat jar file with everything contained in it. But, what I actually want is the configuration files to be located externally. for example I have the following directory structure:

```
bin - contains startup and shutdown scripts
conf - all configurations. i.e. application.properties, logback.xml i18n.properties
logs - log files
libs - app.jar
```

If I use this directory structure and execute the jar using

```
java -cp ./conf -jar ../libs/app.jar
```

then the properties in the conf directory are not loaded or recognized. Is there a better way to do this maintaining the directory structure above? Or, what is the alternative/best practice?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Boot external config](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) is what you are looking for.

Especially it mentions:

> SpringApplication will load properties from `application.properties`
>   files in the following locations and add them to the Spring
>   Environment:
>
> - A /config subdir of the current directory.
> - The current directory
> - A classpath /config package
> - The classpath root

So I would say adding the config folder on classpath is good step. Them it should find `application.properties` and load it automatically.

For different config files I use:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@PropertySource({
                 "classpath:path/some.properties",
                 "classpath:another/path/xmlProperties.xml"
                })
public class MyConfiguration {
  // ...
}
```

**Edit:**
As Dave pointed out (Thank Dave!) there is either *-cp* or *-jar*, so you can't add it to classpath like that. But there are options. This should help you to solve the problem: [Call "java -jar MyFile.jar" with additional classpath option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15930782/call-java-jar-myfile-jar-with-additional-classpath-option).

Additionally `@PropertySource` doesn't require the resources to be classpath resources if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: When you use "-jar" with the Java command there is no "-cp". Another approach is to use a specialized classloader (Spring Boot has such a feature - look up `PropertiesLauncher` in the user guide).

Comment: Thanks, I have missed the way he is launching it! Added a comment to my response.

Answer (score 2):

It should also be mentioned that there is a `spring.config.location` parameter that allows one to specify a file system / classpath location for externalized configuration files. This is documented in the following section of the Spring Boot reference guide:

> http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files

Comment: thanks @btiernay. I saw that in the reference also. Is it the same for i18n properties files? I don't remember seeing anything like that.

Comment: @dondragon2 Not really, but you may be interested in http://justinrodenbostel.com/2014/05/13/part-4-internationalization-in-spring-boot/