# Running JAR file from terminal (Runtime.getRuntime().exec) with both native and .jar dependencies

Tags: java, linux, jar, path, classpath

I am having trouble running a JAR file from terminal which has both native and .jar dependencies. Okay, my goal isn't to run it from the terminal, but to run it as a separate process with Java's Runtime.getRuntime().exec function, but if I can't run it from the terminal, then I also can't run it via. The JAR file I am trying to run depends on a number of other jar files as well as a number of .so libraries. I'm trying to put put all the .jar dependencies and .so dependencies in their own folders and then run the jar file with:

```
java -cp /home/johnmichaelreed/Desktop/Dropbox/Libjitsi_linux_64/* -Djava.library.path=/home/johnmichaelreed/Desktop/Dropbox/Libjitsi_linux_64/lib/native/linux-64/* -jar /home/johnmichaelreed/NetBeansProjects/SendReceive/dist/SendReceive.jar
```

Where "/home/johnmichaelreed/Desktop/Dropbox/Libjitsi_linux_64/" contains all the JAR files and "/home/johnmichaelreed/Desktop/Dropbox/Libjitsi_linux_64/lib/native/linux-64/" contains all the .so files and the main JAR file to run is "/home/johnmichaelreed/NetBeansProjects/SendReceive/dist/SendReceive.jar", but I keep getting this error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class 
.home.johnmichaelreed.Desktop.Dropbox.Libjitsi_linux_64.some-compressed-jar-file.jar
```

Where some-compressed-jar-file.jar is one of the .jar files that my application is supposed to use.

Here's my Java JAR dependencies folder:

[image: Java Jar dependencies]

And here's my native libraries dependencies folder:

[image]

UPDATE:

Okay, this is the solution:

java -Djava.library.path=/home/johnmichaelreed/Desktop/Dropbox/Libjitsi_linux_64/lib/native/linux-64 -cp '/home/johnmichaelreed/NetBeansProjects/SendReceive/dist/SendReceive.jar:/home/j‌​ohnmichaelreed/Desktop/Dropbox/Libjitsi_linux_64/*' Main

With attempt at command line args:

java -Djava.library.path=/home/johnmichaelreed/Desktop/Dropbox/Libjitsi_linux_64/lib/native/linux-64 -cp '/home/johnmichaelreed/NetBeansProjects/SendReceive/dist/SendReceive.jar:/home/j‌​ohnmichaelreed/Desktop/Dropbox/Libjitsi_linux_64/*' Main "arg"

Comment: I'd say the shell expansion of your command (resolving the *) makes the full line incorrect, and java takes one of your jar file as the class name. I'm not sure you can use * in your case, but try wrapping the parameters in quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `-jar` and `-cp` at the same time.

What you can do, is adding your jar to the classpath and then specify your Main class to run. You can also specify the jar dependencies within the manifest of your jar.

Please have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15930782/call-java-jar-myfile-jar-with-additional-classpath-option) for more details.

---

Assuming your Main class is in called `Main` and in the package `foo.bar`, then a possible call may look like:

```
java -cp "/home/johnmichaelreed/Desktop/Dropbox/Libjitsi_linux_64/*;/home/johnmichaelreed/NetBeansProjects/SendReceive/dist/SendReceive.jar" -Djava.library.path="/home/johnmichaelreed/Desktop/Dropbox/Libjitsi_linux_64/lib/native/linux-64/*" foo.bar.Main
```

Comment: Oh. So I should do something like " java -Djava.library.path=/home/johnmichaelreed/Desktop/Dropbox/Libjitsi_linux_64/lib/native/linux-64/* -cp '/home/johnmichaelreed/NetBeansProjects/SendReceive/dist/SendReceive.jar:/home/johnmichaelreed/Desktop/Dropbox/Libjitsi_linux_64/*' main.Main " to specify that I want the native Linux 64 folder to hold .so files, that I want to run my application's jar and everything in the Libjitsi_linux_64 libraries folder, and that the name of the class containing the main method is called "Main".

Comment: Also, the * wildcard isn't recursive, right? Like if I have the same .jar file in the libraries folder and in a subfolder of the libraries folder, it won't load that jar file twice.

Comment: Okay, you were faster than my edit, you're welcome :)

Comment: Oh wait. It's running, but it isn't loading the native libraries. How do you do it with native libraries and also command line args?

Comment: Hm, have you tried to turn around the arguments? So first the `-Djava.library.path`?

Comment: I got it working from the terminal - just had to wrap the args in quotation marks. Thank you.