# Cannot run jar file created from Scala file

Tags: scala, jar, build, sbt

This the code that I have written in Scala.

```
object Main extends App {
    println("Hello World from Scala!")
}
```

This is my *build.sbt*.

```
name := "hello-world"
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.11.5"
mainClass := Some("Main")
```

This is the command that I have run to create the jar file.

```
sbt package
```

My problem is that a jar file named *hello-world_2.11-1.0.jar* has been created at *target/scala-2.11*. But I cannot run the file. It is giving me an error saying *NoClassDefFoundError*.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It also says *what* class is not found. Most likely you aren't including `scala-library.jar`. You can run `scala target/scala-2.11/hello-world_2.11-1.0.jar` if you have Scala 2.11 available from the command line or `java -cp "<path to scala-library.jar>:target/scala-2.11/hello-world_2.11-1.0.jar" Main` (use `;` instead of `:` on Windows).

Comment: I have copied the scala-library.jar in my root folder. So now I am trying to run the following command `java -cp scala-library.jar -jar target/scala-2.11/hello-world_2.11-1.0.jar`. I am getting the same error.

Comment: Sorry, it should be `java -cp "scala-library.jar:target/scala-2.11/hello-world_2.11-1.0.jar" Main` (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/15930980/9204, use `;` instead of `:` on Windows).

Comment: is it possible to include the scala-library.jar file into hello-world jar file?

Comment: Or should I ask a new question for it?

Answer (score 1):

The procedure depicted proves valid up to the way the jar file is executed. From `target/scala-2.11` try running it with

```
scala hello-world_2.11-1.0.jar
```

Check whether it is runnable also from the project root folder with `sbt run`.

Answer (score 1):

To run the jar file(containing scala code) with multiple main classes use following approach

```
scala -cp "<jar-file>.jar;<other-dependencies>.jar" com.xyz.abc.TestApp
```

This command will take care of including scala-library.jar in dependency and will also identify TestApp as main class if it has a `def main(args:Array[String])` method. Please note that multiple jar files should be separated by semi-colon(";")

Answer (score 0):

We can use `sbt-assembly` to package and run the application.

First, create or add the plugin to `project/plugins.sbt`

```
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.9")
```

The sample `build.sbt` looks like below:

```
name := "coursera"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.12.10"
mainClass := Some("Main")
val sparkVersion = "3.0.0-preview2"
val playVersion="2.8.1"

val jacksonVersion="2.10.1"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.scala-lang" % "scala-library" % scalaVersion.toString(),
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion,
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-json" % playVersion,
  // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-streaming-kafka-0-10
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-kafka-0-10" % sparkVersion,
  // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/casbah
  "org.mongodb" %% "casbah" % "3.1.1" pomOnly(),
  // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.typesafe/config
  "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.2.1"
)

assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
  case x => MergeStrategy.first
}
```

From console, we can run `sbt assembly` and the jar file gets created in `target/scala-2.12/` path.

`sbt assembly` will create a fat jar. Here is an excerpt from the documentation :

> sbt-assembly is a sbt plugin originally ported from codahale's assembly-sbt, which I'm guessing was inspired by Maven's assembly plugin. The goal is simple: Create a fat JAR of your project with all of its dependencies.