# External library folder for Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I wonder how to externalize all jdbc drivers for my Spring Boot applications, I would not like to insert jdbc drivers into my fat jar once the application is built.

Is there any way to set a java vm parameter, informing which external folder should be included with jar execution? Or may else exists some kind of spring property for it.

For example:

```
java  -DLib=file:\\\c:\Drivers -jar sample.jar
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See the documentation about PropertiesLauncher:

- https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/executable-jar.html#executable-jar-property-launcher-features

Looks like you can use the `loader.path` property to define a lib folder location, containing jars to load - in fact the lib folder (inline with the jar) is the default location:

> loader.path (if empty) defaults to lib (meaning a local directory or a nested one if running from an archive)

Comment: I still can't make it work with loader.path, it seems to ignore whatever I put in there. Could you add an example, please? Thanks.

Comment: Never mind, it turns out that you need to build your jar with ZIP layout for the loader.path to work.

Comment: Use as below:   java -cp MyOwn.jar -Dloader.path=C:\Sandeep\lib -Dconsole.level=INFO -Dloader.main=abc.Main org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher --spring.config.name=application

Answer (score 1):

CLASSPATH and -classpath will not be working in case of running Spring boot jar file. So there are below options are available:

- Use -Dloader.path e.g.
  java -cp MyOwn.jar -Dloader.path=C:\Sandeep\lib -Dconsole.level=INFO -Dloader.main=abc.Main org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher --spring.config.name=application
- Another option to place other jars into the JRE/lib/ext directory
- Third option, open Spring Boot Jar with WinRAR application and add the jar file into the  Spring Boot jar

Answer (score -2):

Isn't that what the classpath is for? As long as the jdbc driver jars are on the classpath, this should work. Something like this:

```
java -classpath /path/to/driver/jar -jar application.jar
```

You could also set the CLASSPATH environment variable for the same.

Comment: Not with spring-boot and its executable-jar format, and besides you traditionally can't mix the jar and classpath options - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15930782/call-java-jar-myfile-jar-with-additional-classpath-option

Comment: java cmd ignore "classpath" options with jar option.