# How to run a spring-boot jar with external jars which compile with maven dependency system?

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

3rd party jars are not in the repo, may be updated from time to time.

I use dependency in maven as

```
    <dependency>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>$path/$name.jar</systemPath>
   </dependency>
```

to compile and the jars are not in the bundle which is as I wish.

When spring-boot jar is deployed on the target machine, how to run it?

Comment: Start to use a repository manager and avoid system scope dependencies. Apart from that If I correctly remember spring boot maven plugin does take them into account?

Comment: using repo is not an option for this case since it has fixed path on deployed machine and are not managed in the repo

Comment: Your systemPath is a path on the productive machine where you run your application (not a path on the build server)?

Comment: systemPath is the path on the build machine. And unfortunately the path is different form the target machine

Comment: As far as I know, `<dependency>` entries are purely used for _building_ the artifact. The runtime classpath is an entirely different thing. You can not expect your application to "look up" a systemPath from the pom at runtime.

Comment: That's the reason why I ask the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For including a jar from a path into your Spring boot classpath see

[External library folder for Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30745132/927493).

This means that you can safely manage your dependency in your pom by a repo (avoiding sytemPath dependencies).

Answer (score 0):

With SpringBoot project using Maven build tool, you can use:

```
mvn install:install-file "-DgroupId=org.apache.poi" "-DartifactId=poi-ooxml" "-Dpackaging=jar" "-Dfile={your_path_to_jar_file}" "-Dversion=1.1.0"
```

Good luck,