# Starting Spring Boot jar in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar, spring-boot, executable-jar

I am using the spring-boot-maven-plugin to create a WAR file.
I am also using IntelliJ the newest version.

When i try to start it as a JAR Application it wont work because of this error:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java"
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:49904,suspend=y,server=n
-Xmx2048m -classpath "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.1\lib\idea_rt.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.1\lib\util.jar" -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 com.intellij.rt.execution.CommandLineWrapper
C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Temp\classpath0.tmp -jar
C:\development\ui\target\ui-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war

Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:49904', transport:
'socket' Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
-jar
```

In the command line when i am doing `java -jar C:\development\ui\target\ui-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war`, it works quite fine.

I have really no clue why it doesnt work, because the war file exists, and the mainClass is in the right place where i defined it in my pom.

EDIT: 
Ah i disabled the dynamic.classpath and now it works. Does anyone know why this doesnt work with the dynamic classpath turned on?

Answer (score 0):

Because you [cannot specify a classpath and a jar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15930782/476716) to a `java` command line.

It is IntelliJ's mistake to attempt this, filed as [IDEA-147110](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-147110).