# Is there a Maven plugin that runs a non-fat jar?

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

Imagine a normal java maven project with a Main class that produces the artifact project-a.jar. This project has a dependency on project-b.jar.

Is there a Maven plugin that allows to run that jar by a command like that?

```
mvn run-plugin:run org.mygroup:project-a:3.1 <args>
```

The plugin would resolve the runtime dependencies (using META-INF/maven/(...)/pom.xml), install the project and its dependencies to the local maven repository (if not already there), construct the classpath and invoke

```
java -cp (...)/project-a-3.1.jar;(...)/project-b-2.1.jar org.mygroup.Main <args>
```

I know that the usual way is to build an executable (fat) jar that contains the dependencies, but that's not what I am asking for.

Actually, it is not even necesary to read the pom from the jar, because maven can download it from the repositories given the coordinates.

Why this question is different to the [Maven Run Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089285/maven-run-project) question:

I do not want to start from having the project's source already checked out. **So the usual use of the exec plugin is not applicable.** The OP of the Maven Run Project question obviously assumed the presence of a source code project folder. Her purpose was testing and she accepted an answer that clearly needs a project. The wording of both questions is correct, too. There is a difference between the words "**project**" and "**jar**" and their actual meaning in their respective contexts is quite different.

Comment: I think you are looking for maven exec plugin, see possible duplicate: [Maven Run Project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089285/maven-run-project)

Comment: The `META-INF/maven/(...)/pom.xml` structure is not guaranteed to exist. This would be the case when you configure `maven-jar-plugin` with [`addMavenDescriptor`](http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/index.html#class_archive) to `false`.

Comment: No, I think both that question as well as the exec plugin require that you are already in that project (having checked out the source and executing maven from the source code folder containing the pom).

Comment: You should tell us what your big picture is, if you don't want to use the source tree, then I don't think maven is the tool you need. You probably should use  a MANIFEST.MF specifying deps (see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23986765/180100))

Comment: There are already some plugins that don't need a source tree, one of the most obvious is the archetype plugin.

Comment: Would be very nice to have such a plugin, think about it (I usually have a lot of time for that when I move around and assemble those megaton fat jars). And there are situations where disk space counts.

Comment: @not guaranteed to exist: For my own project I can guarantee it, for the dependencies it is not needed.

Comment: My advice, look at the linked answer, choose one of the listed solution and don't try to invent something "strange" (NB: it's just an advice)

Comment: As I already mentioned, the answers of the linked question are not applicable to this question.

Comment: The invoke example is a bit odd: you use either -jar or -cp, you can't combine the two (copied from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15930980/3080094)).

Comment: @vanOekel: true, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `appassembler-maven-plugin` plugin, it creates a shell script that has the dependencies in the classpath for you.  Heres an example config

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>appassembler-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>assemble</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <extraJvmArguments>-Xms256m -Xmx1536m</extraJvmArguments>
                <programs>
                    <program>
                        <mainClass>com.package.MyMainClass</mainClass>
                        <name>TestFormattingUtils</name>
                    </program>
                </programs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

You can find the output script in `.../target/appassembler/bin`  You can manually inspect the script and you'll see that its doing the type of command you wanted where it adds the jars to classpath via the command line.  ie `java -jar (...)/project-a-3.1.jar -cp (...)/project-b-2.1.jar <args>`

Comment: Using a shell is script is not an option, as it must should work on Windows, too.

Comment: It also outputs a windows one, i just never look at it.  Same name, but ends with `.bat`.

Comment: Sounds interesting, I'll have a look at it, but using scripts (and different ones) is somwhat fragile and not very elegant when java and maven are already available.

Comment: I know what you mean.  You can run it though by first invoking the plugin, generating a fresh script then immediately running it.  I wouldn't version control the script or anything like that.  (Or else it would be quite brittle)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a fan of jars-in-jar either, but I do maintain various tools with lots of dependencies. So, at one point, I decided to write an executable `AppBoot` jar which puts all the jars from a lib-subdirectory in a class-loader and then calls the main-method of the desired (executable) jar. This question prompted me to investigate if the `exec-maven-plugin` could do something similar, and it can.

The `exec-maven-plugin` does not require a "Java project" directory, but a `pom.xml` in a directory is required. The `pom.xml` I used is shown below, note that it can be placed in any (empty) directory and the application can be started by opening a shell/prompt in that directory and executing `mvn exec:exec`. Use `mvn -X exec:exec` to review the classpath used by the `exec-maven-plugin`.

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.descartes</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-embed-demo</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <!-- Start the demo using Maven repository artifacts, execute with "mvn exec:exec" -->

    <properties>
        <demo.version>1.2.1.GH</demo.version>
        <mainclass>com.descartes.basicjsp.embed.demo.Launch</mainclass>
        <appname>${project.artifactId}</appname>
        <homedir>${project.basedir}/</homedir>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <!-- exec-maven-plugin will get all required (runtime) jar-files from this dependency. -->
            <groupId>com.descartes</groupId>
            <artifactId>basic-jsp-embed-demo</artifactId>
            <version>${demo.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <!-- The "outputDirectory" is added to the classpath by the exec-maven-plugin. -->
        <!-- Add this pom's directory to the classpath instead of "./target/classes". -->
        <!-- The directory should contain "logback.xml" to prevent a million lines of debug output from Tomcat. -->
        <outputDirectory>${homedir}</outputDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.0</version>
                <!-- mvn exec:exec configuration -->
                <!-- Embedded Tomcat will not stop with "ctrl-c" -->
                <!-- Use http://localhost:8080/shutdown instead -->
                <configuration>
                    <executable>java</executable>
                    <arguments>
                        <argument>-Dapp.name=${appname}</argument>
                        <argument>-Dapp.home.dir=${homedir}</argument>
                        <argument>-Dapp.conf.dir=${homedir}</argument>
                        <argument>-cp</argument>
                        <classpath/>
                        <argument>${mainclass}</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </configuration>
                <!-- mvn exec:java configuration -->
                <!-- "ctrl-c" stops Tomcat but embedded Tomcat fails to start properly, probably a classloader issue. -->
                <!--
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>${mainclass}</mainClass>
                    <systemProperties>
                        <systemProperty>
                            <key>app.name</key>
                            <value>${appname}</value>
                        </systemProperty>
                        <systemProperty>
                            <key>app.home.dir</key>
                            <value>${homedir}/</value>
                        </systemProperty>
                        <systemProperty>
                            <key>app.conf.dir</key>
                            <value>${homedir}/</value>
                        </systemProperty>
                    </systemProperties>
                </configuration>
                -->
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

`AppBoot` is part of the `basic-jsp-embed` project that uses embedded Tomcat and that project can be found [here](https://github.com/intercommit/basic-jsp-embed/releases) (to install, download the latest release, unpack the zip-file and run "mvn install" in the root directory of the multi-module project).

On a side-note: managing a jar-set is tricky, use tools like [jHades](http://jhades.org/) to verify you will not run into trouble with multiple versions of the same class in different jar-files.

Comment: That's not the thing I am looking for, but thanks for the helpful information!

Answer (score -1):

You are looking for the [maven exec plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/).

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.example.Main" [-Dexec.args="argument1"]
```

would run your program

Comment: I don't think this answers the OP question. This command needs to be run on the project source, _not_ the final jar.

Comment: I don't see where you specify the coordinates of the project that you want to execute in your command. How do you specify it? By executing from the project folder... but that is not the question.

Comment: `maven-exec-plugin` runs the compiled `/target/classes/**`, not the final artifact. And in current version 1.6.0 it cannot run a mix of provided and runtime dependencies.

Answer (score -1):

Maven can not do what you want, simply because it has no way to resolve the dependencies of `project A` once it has been built into a final jar.

Maven does not magically download libraries from the Internet: what makes it work are the definition of `repositories` inside the `pom.xml`. Without `pom.xml`, like you seem to suggest, how would it know where to download libraries from? Maven is not a *downloading* tool, it is a project management tool and what you have is no longer a project but a final library.

Since you have control over `project A`, you should really rely on Maven conventions and either build a fat jar or an assembly (with `maven-assembly-plugin`).

By the way, the `pom.xml` file located under `META-INF` is not guaranteed to exist, and, in fact, it is not there if you look at Spring artifacts. Take a look at [Maven Archiver documentation](http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/index.html#class_archive): the presence of this `pom` file is controlled by the `addMavenDescriptor` boolean attribute. Set this attribute to `false` and your main artifact will not have this `pom` file.

Comment: See my comment above. I control project-a and thus can guarantee that it has the pom included. Maven does not need more than that pom to load the dependencies.

Comment: Yes, but because it is not guaranteed, there are no plugins that do what you want...

Comment: You know all maven plugins?