# Calling and opening jar file from command line OS X

Tags: java, maven, jar

I have an issue, which relates to starting a jar file.

I have my code in java, and i have to export it to get a jar file.
I do that, and i get a jar file, however, now i want to call my jar file from the command line. I set my main class in my jar file, so that i have an entry point. My java code depends on another jar file, and i am not sure, if it has anything to do with my problem.

Then i call the file from command line, after i have positioned myself in the right folder. I use the command : java -jar Likvidator2.jar

And what i get is this :

[image: Error Message]

I have tried checking my java version, and updating it, but at this point i really am not sure what to do and where to go anymore. Is it possible that i am building my project wrong, or something ?

Comment: A jar file does not contain dependencies...

Comment: You have to either add the dependencies to the classpath, or repackage all dependencies into your jar. Since you appear to use maven, take a look at the maven shade plugin: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/

Comment: i have just checked my pom.xml file, and there is a dependency to a jar that i use, im confused

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15930782/call-java-jar-myfile-jar-with-additional-classpath-option

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the classpath to the command.

```
java -classpath <pathtodependency.jar;pathtootherdep.jar> your.MainClass
```

Comment: Whoever did downvote me, please comment. This is really rude. Besides my answer is correct.

Comment: You cannot combine -classpath and -jar with -jar the Claspath must be in the manifest.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15930782/call-java-jar-myfile-jar-with-additional-classpath-option

Comment: A small hint before down voting would be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [Maven Shade Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/executable-jar.html) to create an executable JAR, as [@Jan Doerrenhaus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/321356/jan-doerrenhaus) already commented.

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED]

I just had to build the jar file as runnable jar file, and everything worked fine.