# Add twitter4j to classpath in Command Prompt

Tags: java, netbeans, twitter4j

I'm currently working on a small project. The first step is to pull tweets from given IDs using the twitter4j API. However, my issue is this error:

> TweetCleaner.java:14: error: package twitter4j does not exist

whenever I attempt to compile my code from the command line:

javac -classpath twitter4j-core-4.0.4.jar MyProgram.java

The above command, however, does not do the trick.

I am using Eclipse and I've added the twitter4j jar files to my Libraries.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass additional resources from command line for the execution of your class you can use the following command:

```
java -cp 'MyProgram.jar:<twitter_jar_folder>/twitter4j.jar' main.Main
```

you can take a look at this question for more: [Call "java -jar MyFile.jar" with additional classpath option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15930782/call-java-jar-myfile-jar-with-additional-classpath-option)

Comment: Don't you have to use the javac command first to compile your code?

Also, I just want to make sure I follow. My class is called TweetCleaner. So the command I'd want to use is:

> java -cp 'TweetCleaner.jar:<twitter_jar_folder>/twitter4j.jar' TweetCleaner