# Setting classpath from start script does not work

Tags: java, bash, classpath

I have a bash script to start my application. My application is a spring application bundled as a FAT Jar with following Manifest entries.

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Implementation-Title: My App
Implementation-Version: 1.0-SNAPSHOT
Implementation-Build: 0aef5a1f96de18795c76b896e349c741d9
Implementation-Date: Sep 21, 2016 07:02:48 GMT
Created-By: 1.8.0_77 (Oracle Corporation)
Implementation-Vendor: App Team
Main-class: com.demo.ApplicationInitializer
```

I put this under a folder `/Users/nn/apps/myapp/instance1`. This applications needs a config file `configs.yml` from classpath and it was decided that this should be outside of the JAR file. This is the reason why I created a folder `/Users/nn/apps/myapp/shared` and put this `configs.yml` under it. In my startup script (`start.sh`), I am adding following code to set the classpath:

```
JAVA_CLASSPATH="/Users/nn/apps/myapp/shared:/Users/nn/apps/myapp/instance1"
JAVA_CLASSPATH="$JAVA_CLASSPATH:/Users/nn/apps/myapp/shared/configs.yml"
export CLASSPATH=$JAVA_CLASSPATH

java <my_other_settings> -jar myapp-fatjar.jar
```

I get exception that `configs.yml` is not in classpath (a Spring bean in my app tries to load this which throws exception).

I have also tried explicitly passing `-classpath` to `java` command pointing to `$JAVA_CLASSPATH`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following start.sh script:

```
JAVA_CLASSPATH="/Users/nn/apps/myapp/shared:/Users/nn/apps/myapp/instance1"
JAVA_CLASSPATH="$JAVA_CLASSPATH:/Users/nn/apps/myapp/shared/configs.yml"
JAVA_CLASSPATH="$JAVA_CLASSPATH:myapp-fatjar.jar"


java -cp $JAVA_CLASSPATH com.demo.ApplicationInitializer
```

see https://stackoverflow.com/a/15930980/4473044

Comment: Its interesting to know that both `-cp` and `-jar` cannot be combined. And, this was what exactly causing issue for me.