# Is it possible to have a jar Manifest to use all jars in a folder

Tags: java, jar, dependencies, manifest

I'm trying to set a jar manifest so it loads all the libraries (jars) within a folder next to the jar.

The manifest looks like this:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: libs/
Main-Class: path.to.my.class.Main
```

The layout is as follows:

```
- MyJar.jar
- libs/
-----lib1.jar
-----lib2.jar
```

And I'm trying to run like this:

```
java -jar MyJar.jar
```

And I get NoClassDefinition errors about classes in the jar within the folder.

In case someone is curious, this folder might contain optional jars that are processed during class loading. That' swhy I can't use the hardcoded or autogenerated ones.

Any idea?

**Update**
Rephrased the question as this is not currently possible from the manifest itself. The answer was the only really viable without the need of extracting the jars, although it also works.

So as a summary the answer is no, this can't be done from manifest file alone if you have unespecified dependencies.

Comment: AFIK JAR's classpath starts at the root of the `JAR` file. You can't put classes or JARs in sub directories unless you're going to load them dynamically like `Spring Boot` or `OSGI` containers.

Comment: Turns out, it can be done, you have to specify path with the JAR name. Check this link http://todayguesswhat.blogspot.com/2011/03/jar-manifestmf-class-path-referencing.html?_sm_au_=ivVTSRf571T1SvZP

Comment: I ran across that link earlier and my manifest above is based on that but it doesn't work. It only finds the files within that folder that are defined in the classpath. The folder alone doesn't seem to work. (i.e. libs/ or ./libs/)

Comment: According to the link `Class-Path: ./libs/lib1.jar` should work.

Comment: Yes it does, but I don't know the dependencies before hand. I would like to use all jars in there without the need of knowing before hand. Is for a plugin system.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

java does not know the jar files in the libs directory.
If you are using java 1.6+, You can run program as

java -cp lib/* -jar MyJar.jar

Comment: Didn't work as written. had to do this: java -cp libs/ -jar MyJar.jar. Sadly this is not what I asked as I'm trying to see if it's possible from the manifest.

Comment: I ended up using a version of this to make it work: java -cp libs/* path.to.my.class.Main

Comment: Updated question to accomodate this as the only vaid answer.

Comment: java does not allow both `-cp` and `-jar` flags: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15930782/call-java-jar-myfile-jar-with-additional-classpath-option

Answer (score 2):

You should define your Manifest classpath as

```
Class-Path: libs/lib1.jar libs/lib2.jar
```

See Oracle documentation for more details https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html

Comment: That only works if you know before hand the jars that the folder will have. This is intended for optional jars that the application detects when they are in the classpath.

Comment: Did you try Class-Path: libs/*.jar ?

Comment: Apparently Class-Path entry in manifest file did not support wildcards

Comment: Yes, Class-Path entry in manifest file did not support wildcards, but a decent project has symbolic links without the version numbers to link.

Answer (score 1):

Try extracting these jars. It looks like you cannot add all jars from directory but you can add all classes. You lose obviously all configuration in manifest, however, if you are interested in jars' code content only, it might work.

I tested that with these simple classes

```
import pkg.B;

public class A {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(B.class.getName());
  }
}

package pkg;

public class B {}
```

now I try to separate the classes. I have jarred them into

```
$ jar tf libA.jar 
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
A.class
$ jar tf libB.jar 
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
pkg/B.class
```

no Class-Path in any manifest. I can run A with `java -cp libB.jar:libA.jar A`. Now I create another jar with Class-Path set to `lib/`

```
$ cat manifest 
Class-Path: lib/
$ jar cfm empty.jar manifest
```

my directory tree look like

```
$ ls -R
.:
A.java  empty.jar  lib  lib.jar  manifest  pkg

./lib:
libA.jar  libB.jar

./pkg:
B.java
```

Now I try jar

```
$ java -jar empty.jar 
Error: Could not find or load main class A
```

Hopeless, right? Then I extracted libA.jar and libB.jar into lib (same as [this guy][2]). Now all is fine

```
$ java -jar empty.jar 
pkg.B
```

Comment: This just won't work for my scenario as non-technical users won't be able to do this. Asking them to put jars in a directory is hard enough. Thanks