# Access classes defined in a jar file, from within (for instance) JRuby irb?

Tags: java, jruby

(Crossposting note: I have asked this question one week ago at the JRuby mailing list, but didn't get any answer yet).

I have a jar file provided by someone else, no access to the source code. The jar file is in lib/other/appl.jar, the class is named Appl, and the package is com.abc.xyz

I would like to instantiate an Appl object from the JRuby irb, jirb_swing_ex.

(Of course my problem applies not only to jirb, but to running JRuby programs in general, but I explain it in the way I'm using it right now, just in case there are some peculiarities in Jirb which need special treatment).

**THIS is the way it DOES work**:

(1) Invoke jirb by:

```
java -jar jr/jruby-complete-1.7.27 jb/jirb_swing_ex
```

(2) Put the directory with the jar file into the load path:

```
$: << 'lib/other'
```

(3) Load the jar file

```
require 'appl.jar'
```

(4) Import the class

```
java_import com.abc.xyz.Appl
```

(5) Create the object

```
x = Appl.new
```

As I said, this works, and I can live with it if necessary, but I would prefer a simpler approach:

**NOW TO MY QUESTION**: Instead of fiddling around with load path and doing a `require` for the Jar file, I thought I could let Java already include the jar file. This is what I have tried:

```
java -cp lib/other/appl.jar -jar jr/jruby-complete-1.7.27 jb/jirb_swing_ex
```

The problem is: How can I get at my object? If I just use the class name *com.abc.xyz.Appl*, JRuby complains that the class not found (*NameError: missing class name*).

BTW, I have also tried forward slashes (since I'm on Windows), i.e.

```
java -cp lib\other\appl.jar -jar jr\jruby-complete-1.7.27 jb\jirb_swing_ex
```

but the same effect. I had expected that, having appl.jar in my class path, would make the classes available somehow, but I seem to miss something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Running `jirb` or `jirb_swing` with custom class path

`jirb` and `jirb_swing` will use the value of `JRUBY_CP` environment variable (if present) to extend class path given to Java command line.

Example with commons-lang3 library taken from my local maven repository, using bash on Linux or macOS:

```
$ export JRUBY_CP=${HOME}/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.4/commons-lang3-3.4.jar

$ jirb
irb(main):001:0> org.apache.commons.lang3.mutable.MutableBoolean.new
=> #<Java::OrgApacheCommonsLang3Mutable::MutableBoolean:0x7c24b813>
```

### Running JRuby programs with custom class path

To run a JRuby program that uses a third-party java library, this won't work:

```
java -cp lib/other/appl.jar -jar jr/jruby-complete-1.7.27 ...
```

You must use [either `-jar` or `-cp`, you can't combine the two](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15930980/6730571).
From `java` man page:

> When you use this option [-jar], the JAR file is the source of all user classes, and other user class path settings are ignored.

In addition, you need to pass the main Java class, which is `org.jruby.Main`, and that class needs arguments: either a path to a Ruby script, or other command line arguments such as `-e 'puts 2+2'`.

So the command line structure is the following:

```
# Run script file:
java -cp path/to/jruby.jar:other/custom.jar org.jruby.Main path/to/script
# Run simple one-line Ruby program
java -cp path/to/jruby.jar:other/custom.jar org.jruby.Main -e 'some ruby here'
```

(on Windows please use `;` instead of `:` as separator)

Actual example with same commons-lang3 library & OS:

```
$ alias myjruby="java -cp ${JRUBY_HOME}/lib/jruby.jar:${HOME}/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.4/commons-lang3-3.4.jar org.jruby.Main"

# Verifying base jruby code works with that:
$ myjruby -e 'puts 2+2'
4

# Now verifying it can use my 3rd-party lib:
$ myjruby -e 'puts org.apache.commons.lang3.mutable.MutableBoolean.new'
false
```

Comment: You are right that my jirb_swing_ex is a modified jirb_swing. Unfortunately, if I do a `java -cp jr\jruby-complete-1.7.27:lib\other\appl.jar jb\jirb_swing_ex`,  Java doesn't find my main class (in jirb_swing_ex) anymore. The error message is: *Fehler: Hauptklasse C:.cygwin64.home.fisrona.gitwrk.vp5.bin.jirb_swing_ex konnte nicht gefunden oder geladen werden*

Comment: To start `jirb_swing_ex` with extended class path, you should perhaps use the first  method of my answer, a bit easier I think. On Windows it would be `%JRUBY_CP%`. The second approach executes the JRuby main class, which takes an arbitrary Ruby program as argument, but there are at least 2 problems with your attempt: 1) on Windows the separator for class path is `;` not `:` -- 2) You omitted the JRuby main class -- So you need to try with `java -cp jr\jruby-complete-1.7.27:lib\other\appl.jar org.jruby.Main jb\jirb_swing_ex` (please note the 2 changes)