# Reference an external jar file at runtime for, an executable jar file

Tags: java, shared-libraries, external

I have an Inventory control application (Warehouse.jar) with a module (ACS.jar) which depends on classes inside Warehouse.jar. Now, here is my issue. When I generate ACS.jar (another executable jar) using Intellij, it builds the ACS executable jar artifact folder with a copy of Warehouse.Jar in that folder. I am compelled to place both executable jar files into the same folder, but if the executables are in separate folders, how do I configure ACS.Jar to reference Warehouse.Jar at runtime from that separate folder?

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/q/15930782/803925

Comment: nbrooks. Thanks for your assistance. I was unable to find any direct help from the link you posted, but it got me to thinking. I opened the ACS executable jar with WinRar, navigated to the manifest file (MANIFEST.MF) and changed placed the relative path to Warehouse.jar and it works! Thank you sir