# Why i cant open a jar file after creating it with IntelliJ

Tags: java, jar

I created a jar file with IntelliJ. I tried to open it with the cmd. But i got java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError because i build the jar with JDK 15 and it tried open it with Java 8, so i tried open it with Java 15 and got this
Error: Unable to initialize main class sample.JobegaGUI
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/itextpdf/layout/element/IBlockElement

I used this command in the folder where the jar is saved. I hoped the command was right.

"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.2\bin\java" -jar Jobega.jar

I'm using iText7-Core-7.1.3

I don't know what i can do anymore.
I hope you can help me. Just say if you need to see some files.

Comment: here is your problem: Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/itextpdf/layout/element/IBlockElement

Comment: *"I'm using iText7-Core-7.1.3"* looking at how you're launching your application you're not putting the itext jar in your classpath.

Comment: You can either put the itext jar in your classpath or package a **fat jar**. See more at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven

Comment: the problem is i dont use a itext jar it is a folder with the different jars in it. I added it under project setting to the libaries.

Comment: @Berni you still need to add those jars to the classpath if they're needed at runtime. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15930980/133203) for instructions on how to do it.

Comment: Under Project Settings -> Modules -> Dependencies i add all Jars and add them under Classpath in the Manifest.mf file build the jar new and try open it. And the same Error appears

Comment: i think im just too dumb