# "NoClassDefFoundError" when the jar file built by Intellij Idea artifacts was executed in command line

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, noclassdeffounderror

I have a problem with running my jar execution file built by Intellij Idea Artifacts in command line. Error message is

```
NoClassDefFoundError: io.mattmoore.kotlin.playground.cinterop.Greeter
```

But it worked when I use the IDE to execute "RUN".

Do you have any Idea why is that happening?

Highly appreciated if someone could give me a hint about how to fix it.

[image: Intellij Idea project]

Harrison

Comment: How is this c++ related? Please don't use irrelevant tags

Answer (score 0):

IDE knows better where to find dependencies, but once you export `.jar` file, you need to manually ensure that no dependency is missing
(and that all get loaded).

### Example:

To run `MyProgram.jar`, place all your dependencies inside of `libs` directory (which you need to create beside it), then use command like:

```
java -cp 'MyProgram.jar:libs/*' my_package.MyMainClass
```

**OR** <sup>for Windows (use semicolon)</sup>

```
java -cp 'MyProgram.jar;libs/*' my_package.MyMainClass
```

> **Note** that dependency means other `.jar` files, for example, the one that defines `io.mattmoore.kotlin.playground.cinterop.Greeter` class.

See also [How to call "`.jar`” with additional classpath option?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15930980/8740349)

Comment: If I remember correctly, Intellij copies all dependencies for you automatically into some directory which's name I forgot, so use that name instead of `libs` (I mean, this is how you run Java without IDE, and adding artifacts to IDE does not change it!)

Comment: Thanks, I follow your suggestion, but still got same error as shown below:
$ ls -l
total 3456
-rw-r--r--  1 xxx  staff     3049 Aug 21 10:53 kotlin-cinterop-talk.main.jar
drwxr-xr-x  3 xxx  staff       96 Aug 21 13:14 libs
ls lib*
\greeter-klib-jvm.jar
$ java -cp 'kotlin-cinterop-talk.main.jar:libs/*' io.mattmoore.kotlin.playground.cinterop.Greeter 
錯誤: 在類別 io.mattmoore.kotlin.playground.cinterop.Greeter 中找不到主要方法，請定義主要方法為:
   public static void main(String[] args)
或者 JavaFX 應用程式類別必須擴充 javafx.application.Application

Comment: I am using mac os version 10.15.6, thanks

Comment: Only classes that define valid `main` method can be passed in command line, but as I think you already have `main`-class somewhere and is linked in manifest, simply run `java -cp 'kotlin-cinterop-talk.main.jar:libs/*'` (without class name); and I hope you are not trying to run an artifact? (I mean, your `.jar` name is strange)