# BoofCV: Unresolved Compilation Problems

Tags: java, maven, raspberry-pi, qr-code, boofcv

I'm using a Raspberry Pi (4) and hoped I'd be able to implement QR detection through a Rasp Cam. I found BoofCV that could do the job - so I copied the code from the [ExampleDetectQrCode](https://github.com/lessthanoptimal/BoofCV/blob/SNAPSHOT/examples/src/main/java/boofcv/examples/fiducial/ExampleDetectQrCode.java) repo but its throwing a few errors...

```
var cannot be resolved to a type
VisualizeShapes cannot be resolved
VisualizeShapes cannot be resolved
ShowImages cannot be resolved
```

On my imports I'm also getting:

```
The import boofcv.gui cannot be resolved
```

I used Maven to implement BoofCV, I'm **very** new to Maven but I think I've done it right (again just copied straight from the repo [home](https://github.com/lessthanoptimal/BoofCV)):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.boofcv</groupId>
  <artifactId>boofcv-core</artifactId>
  <version>0.40.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import the "boofcv-swing" artifact to have the built in Swing components.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.boofcv</groupId>
  <artifactId>boofcv-swing</artifactId>
  <version>0.40.1</version>
</dependency>
```

If your application doesn't have a GUI you will want to remove anything that's in the boofcv.gui package as that will try to open a window.

Comment: Thanks, that worked to get rid of the GUI errors and I sorted the Var problem. However I'm now getting:
`Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: boofcv/struct/image/ImageGray`.

Comment: that's really weird since that class is defined in "boofcv-core". Does it build just fine but you get that error when you run it?

Comment: Yeah I only get that error when I run it, build is fine

Comment: you're missing a jar or two  in the class path

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15930782/call-java-jar-myfile-jar-with-additional-classpath-option

Comment: Yes you're right. Managed to get it sorted! Cheers