# java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc

Tags: java, mysql, maven, jdbc, centos

I am attempting to run some queries using JDBC and keep getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: error
        at com.mycompany.app.App.writer(App.java:195)
        at com.mycompany.app.App.main(App.java:19)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname
```

here is the relevant part of my code:

```
public class App {
           writer();
}

public static void writer() {
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname
        String username = "root";
        String password = "password";
        try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password)) {
            Statement st = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet r= st.executeQuery("insert query here");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("error");
        }

    }
}
```

When I run it through Intellij Idea it works, but I need it to run on a server running Centos.
I have tried running it with this commands:

```
 javac -cp "filepath/mysql-connector-java-5.1.35-bin.jar" App.java  
 java -cp ".filepath/mysql-connector-java-5.1.35-bin.jar" App
```

I have tried running it using maven, including

```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.35</version>
    </dependency>
```

in pom.xml  and still get the same error

I have looked through many articles online (and stack questions) and still can't find the solution.

The server is running CentoOS 6.6 and the database is running locally.

I am using:

java version "1.8.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)

Comment: What version of Java are you using?

Comment: I added it to the main post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entries on the classpath on Unix-like operating systems must be separated by `:`. Add a `:` between `.` (which indicates the current directory) and the path of the jar:

```
java -cp .:filepath/mysql-connector-java-5.1.35-bin.jar App
```

Comment: @RichSala Are you sure the path to the jar for the JDBC driver is correct?

Comment: Apparently not lol.  Thanks, It worked!  I really need it to work in maven, but I can probably figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you may place your `mysql-connector-java-5.1.35-bin.jar` to the following directory -

```
JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/ext
```

If you place the `jar` in this directory then you don't have to add it to `classpath` by using command.

Comment: This solves the issue but it's like killing a bug with a flamethrower.

Answer (score 0):

You can try loading the driver class using `class.forName("qualified name of driver class")`. This should resolve the issue if you're not facing the issue of class path with maven. Have a look [at this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30818775/4373996) where
 the index tag was removed from pom and it worked.