# IntelliJ Build Artifact causes executable .jar to ignore Class-Path setting

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

When I create an executable .jar file using IntelliJ, the .jar file always ignores it's own class-path in the manifest.mf file.

Thanks to this question: [Executable JAR ignores its own Class-Path attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10436517/executable-jar-ignores-its-own-class-path-attribute) I have been able to find that the cause of the problem is that during the creation of the .jar file, a META-INF/LIST.MF file is created. If I delete that file, everything works fine. However, unlike the question linked, my pom.xml file does not contain the command to create this file.

How do I turn this off in IntelliJ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45169655/104891 may be the case. This file may come from one of the dependent jars included in the artifact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try, when creating an artifact in IntelliJ,`project structure -> Artifacts -> new from maven with dependencies`, in the path for `Directory for the META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`, always change the path to the sibling `resources` `directory, it should not be set to`java` directory.