# Maven: how to query the executable classpath?

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, pom.xml

I have a maven project with some specified dependencies.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
  <version>2.4</version>
</dependency>
```

How can I query maven to find out the path it's using for these dependencies, or the classpath I should use for independent execution?

My goal is to build a wrapper which runs the program with the appropriate classpath.

Comment: I updated my answer with further details, hope that helps

Comment: @A.DiMatteo, it does help, thanks.  Is there a place that tells how to install these plugins?

Comment: Sure, from official Maven documentation, here https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html#How_do_I_use_plug-ins a short introduction on how to use plugins, then on each plugin site there are several examples, I'll update my answer further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several alternatives are available in Maven:

### Maven Dependency Plugin (build-classpath goal)

Look at the Maven Dependency Plugin, especially the [build-classpath](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/build-classpath-mojo.html) goal provides exactly the full classpath for external execution usages. Among many options, The `outputFile` parameter may be helpful.
You don't need to configure it for usage, just run

```
mvn dependency:build-classpath
```

On your project and you'll see the classpath as part of the build output. Or

```
mvn dependency:build-classpath -Dmdep.outputFile=classpath.txt
```

To redirect just the classpath to a file.

### Maven Dependency Plugin (copy-dependencies goal)

To build a wrapper, you could also look at the [copy-dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html) goal, which would copy the required dependencies (jars), including transitive dependencies, to a configured folder (so you don't need hardcoded paths to your local machine).
An example of plugin configuration is available on the official site, [here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/copying-project-dependencies.html).
For instance, the following configuration:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.10</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/dependencies</outputDirectory>
                        <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                        <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                        <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                        <includeScope>runtime</includeScope>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Would add to the folder `target/dependencies` all the dependencies declared in scope `compile`. NOTE: with respect to the linked official example, I added the  `<includeScope>runtime</includeScope>` configuration entry (which will include compile and runtime scoped dependencies, according to [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html) and my tests), otherwise it would also include the `test` scope by default (which is something I believe you would not need at runtime).

### Exec Maven Plugin (java or exec goals)

Alternatively, you can use the [Exec Maven Plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/) to execute a `main` from Maven using the required classpath.
An example of plugin configuration is available on the official site, [here](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/examples/example-exec-for-java-programs.html).
The following configuration for instance:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>my-execution</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>java</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <mainClass>com.sample.MainApp</mainClass>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Will configure the Exec plugin to run via `mvn exec:java` the main class `MainApp` as configured, obviously with the required classpath.

### Maven Assembly Plugin

Lastly, the [Maven Assembly Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) also provides facilities to build an executable jar with dependencies, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven), in another question on stackoverflow.